# VRP standstill query

Tags: optaplanner

What is purpose of Standstill in VRP? I am trying to understand below rule in VRP example. What is previousStandstill?

```
rule "distanceToPreviousStandstill"
    when
        $customer : Customer(previousStandstill != null, $distanceFromPreviousStandstill : distanceFromPreviousStandstill)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $distanceFromPreviousStandstill);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previousStandstill is Vehicle or another Customer.

Ex.
ROUTE = VEHICLE(depot) -> CUSTOMER A -> CUSTOMER B -> CUSTOMER C -> CUSTOMER D

previousStandstill for CUSTOMER B is CUSTOMER A

previousStandstill for CUSTOMER A is VEHICLE

Vehicle location is the same as the location of depot.

So this rule add soft score for all distance in route except last part from CUSTOMER D to Vehicle